# Creating a MonoGame app with multiple screens

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xna, monogame

I’m trying to create a MonoGame base app which runs on 1-8 screens.

I was tried to do it by creating multiple Game objects on every monitor and render them
by running an internal while loop which responsible to call “RunOneFrame” method
for every game.

It works fine, but I have seen that the “RunOneFrame” method is used for tests and debug purposes only.
Plus, I have some lags in it…

What is the best practice for that requirement? Is it even possible on MonoGame?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the WindowsDX platform(only) on Monogame there is a function called `GameWindow.CreateWindow()`

You can use the following code in game1.cs:

```
//Additional using statement at the top of file
using System.Windows.Forms;

//...

//class level variables
private const int SCREENX = 800, SCREENY = 600;
private SwapChainRenderTarget[] _swapChain = new SwapChainRenderTarget[7];  // 7 + main window

//...

protected override void Initialize()
{
     GameWindow _otherWindow;

     for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
     {    
     _otherWindow = GameWindow.Create(this, SCREENX, SCREENY);
     Form _newForm = Form.FromHandle(_otherWindow.Handle);

     // move to target window based on desktop layout
     _newForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(SCREENX * (x + 1) % 4, SCREENY * (x + 1) / 4); 
     //  assuming all of the screens are the same size and in a 4 wide by 2 high config
     //  with the the primary in the top left
     
     _newForm.Visible = true; // show the form
     _newForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

     _swapChain[x] = new SwapChainRenderTarget(this.GraphicsDevice,
                                             _otherWindow.Handle,
                                             _otherWindow.ClientBounds.Width,
                                             _otherWindow.ClientBounds.Height,
                                             false,
                                             SurfaceFormat.Color,
                                             DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8,
                                             1,
                                             RenderTargetUsage.PlatformContents,
                                             PresentInterval.Default);
    }
base.Initialize();
}

//...

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
        {
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_swapChain[i]);
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
            // TODO Add screen i draw code here(0-7)
            _swapChain[i].Present(); 
        }

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        // TODO Draw primary screen here
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Mouse control is tricky and probably worthy of a different question.
The basic idea is each screen has its own `MouseState`. So the code is `Mouse.GetState(_otherWindow)`

All of the screens` coordinate systems (including mouse) are local, i.e. (0,0) is top left of each screen.

You will need a beefy GPU with lots of VRAM.  This code will require 8 times the CPU-GPU data transfer bandwidth.  I would do a test on `gameTime.IsrunningSlowly == true` to see if it is taking too long to render, if so, set the `TargetElapsedTime` to a slower rate(the default of 60 FPS is 16.67 ms)